# How to use bootstrap color classes in jqgrid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

How to use bootstrap color classes in latest free jqgrid to conditionally change text color in table column ?

I tried bootstrap color class

```
$grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'Unpaidsum', {
    cellattr: function(rowId, val, rawObject) {

        if ( new Date(rawObject.Duedate   ) < new Date()   ) {
            return " class='text-danger'";
        }
    }

});
```

and jquery-ui color class

```
return " class='ui-state-error-text'";
```

But those does not change color.

Only jquery ui class

```
return " class='ui-state-error'";
```

works but this changes background also.
How to use some predefined class to change color without returning style attribute in cellattr ?

Comment: Which Bootrsrap class you want to use? `"danger"`, `"text-danger"`, "bg-danger", `"text-warning"`, `bg-warning`, ...?

Comment: @Oleg  In some case text-danger, text-warning etc. to change only color. In come other cases bg-danger, bg-warning to change only background. Using `ui-state-error` causes ugly sunken 2d effect on jqgrid cell.

Comment: @Oleg. This is posted also in https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/266

Comment: Look at [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/266#issuecomment-244490482).

Comment: @Oleg Thak you. It was my mistake, question was wrong. I posted more precise question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318419/how-to-apply-column-template-after-jqgrid-is-created