# How to apply column template after jqgrid is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid does not allw to apply column template after it is created.
I tried

```
  var newOrderPriceTemplate = {
    align: "center",
    formatter: "showlink",
    formatoptions: {
        onClick: function() { alert('clicked'); }
    }
    };

    $(function () {
      ... code to create jqgrid into $grid
      $grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'Hind', {
        template: newOrderPriceTemplate,
        search: false
    }); 
    });
```

alert box does not appear if clicked in column.
search: false removes search field properly so setColProp is executed.

How to apply newOrderPriceTemplate after jqgrid is created but before displayed.
If template is specified in colModel at creation time, it works.

Latest free jqgrid, jquery, bootstrap 3, aps.net mvc4 , .net 4.6 are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are misunderstanding how templates works. Template is nothing more as the list of settings which will be used in `$.extend` to combine some current properties from `colModel` with another object of *template* properties.

I recommend to read [the code fragment](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.4/js/grid.base.js#L4827-L4842) of the code of free jqGrid. In simplified form the code looks like

```
for (iCol = 0; iCol < p.colModel.length; iCol++) {
    p.colModel[iCol] = $.extend(true, {},
        p.cmTemplate,
        p.colModel[iCol].template || {},
        p.colModel[iCol]);
}
```

In other words jqGrid combines the values from `cmTemplate`, `template` property of the column with the property of `colModel`. jqGrid does it **at the beginning** of creating the grid.

Thus if you have some template (`newOrderPriceTemplate` for example), which you need to apply *after the grid is created*, then you need just use `$.extend` manually to extend (and overwrite) the existing properties:

```
var p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam");

p.colModel[p.iColByName.Hind] = $.extend(true, {},
    p.colModel[p.iColByName.Hind], // old values
    newOrderPriceTemplate,         // the applied template
    { search: false }              // one more setting to apply
);
```

It's important to place new properties *after* the current settings from `p.colModel[p.iColByName.Hind]` to be able to overwrite there.

Comment: Thank you. Is it reasonable to change setColProp so that it will apply this automatically if template property is set ?

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! First of all I wanted *to explain* why your current code not work. You can use `setColProp` if you want, but the code of `setColProp` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.4/js/grid.custom.js#L44-L55)) consists mostly from one line `$.extend(true, p.colModel[p.iColByName[colname]], obj);` and one can use it directly. Moreover, you wanted to apply **two** sets of properties: `newOrderPriceTemplate` **and** `{search: false}`. Thus the usage of one `$.extend` with multiple parameters seems to me easier and more understandable.